# Composer installs only globally (Windows 10)

Tags: composer-php, windows-10

When I try to install Composer (exe installer, curl, tried all methods), it installs only in `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin` and never localy, even if I run it (obviously) from another directory.

When I run `composer init` - it does not create json config anywhere, `composer install` - is installing only in `C:/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/Composer/`

```
D:\test>composer init

←[37;44m                                            ←[39;49m
←[37;44m  Welcome to the Composer config generator  ←[39;49m
←[37;44m                                            ←[39;49m


This command will guide you through creating your composer.json config.

Package name (<vendor>/<name>) [←[33mUsername/test←[39m]: test/test
Description []:
Author []: test <test@test.test>
Minimum Stability []:
Package Type []:
License []:

Define your dependencies.

Would you like to define your dependencies (require) interactively [←[33myes←[39m]?
Search for a package:
Would you like to define your dev dependencies (require-dev) interactively [←[33myes←[39m]?
Search for a package:

{
    "name": "test/test",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "email": "test@test.test"
        }
    ],
    "require": {}
}

D:\test>dir

29.08.2015  12:39    <DIR>          .
29.08.2015  12:39    <DIR>          ..
               0 files

D:\test>composer require slim/slim -vvv
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (CWD): hg branch
Executing command (CWD): svn info --xml
Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Loading config file C:/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (CWD): hg branch
Executing command (CWD): svn info --xml
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014-10.json from cache Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-01.json from cache Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-04.json from cache Downloading http://packagist.org/p/provider-2015-07$bf4d7ab35da85686431ee3c47d0d6d2eee3d913013b38506fbc197c5e95c2420.json
Writing C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-07.json into cache Downloading http://packagist.org/p/provider-latest$ee6937b535cc76629a8e81c4362790bd14ce6a824def5d75f7222438e756a7b0.json
Writing C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json into cache
Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-slim$slim.json from cache Using version ←[32m^2.6←[39m for ←[32mslim/slim←[39m
←[32m./composer.json has been updated←[39m
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (CWD): hg branch
Executing command (CWD): svn info --xml
Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Loading config file C:/Users/Username/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (CWD): hg branch
Executing command (CWD): svn info --xml
←[32mLoading composer repositories with package information←[39m
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
←[32mUpdating dependencies (including require-dev)←[39m
Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014-10.json from cache Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-01.json from cache Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-04.json from cache Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-07.json from cache Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json from cache
Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-slim$slim.json from cache Analyzed 63 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 45 rules to resolve dependencies
  - Installing ←[32mslim/slim←[39m (←[33m2.6.2←[39m)
Reading C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Composer/files/slim/slim/20a02782f76830b67ae56a5c08eb1f563c351a37.zip from cache
    Loading from cache
    Extracting archive

    REASON: Required by root: Install command rule (install slim/slim 2.6.0|install slim/slim 2.6.1|install slim/slim 2.6.2)

←[32mWriting lock file←[39m
←[32mGenerating autoload files←[39m
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Before applying all steps, try step 5 with your current setup.

## Installation Steps

1. Manually download: https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
2. place `composer.phar` into your PHP folder, next to `php.exe`
3. add a batch file `composer.bat` in the same folder (to execute composer a bit easier), with the following content:

   ```
   @echo off
   ::  Composer CLI Shortcut (Global Installation)
   "%~dp0php.exe" "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
   pause
   ```
4. add the PHP folder to your ENV path, so that `php` and `composer` are available on any path
5. then create your new project

   - `mkdir slim`
   - `cd slim`
   - `composer require slim/slim 2.6.2 -vvv` (this time with version)